# Grouping of Entity Objects in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-interface, user-controls, silverlight-toolkit

I have the following DB structure and I have a hard time displaying it within a Silverlight window:

Person->PersonCamp<-Camp->CampActivities<-Activity

I have a WCF RIA domain service that encapsulates all entities and the right query methods on the service.

The problem is that the UI has to display the activities by camp in the following manner:

```
->Camp Name:
   ->ActivityCheckbox(Key) + Activity Name
   ->ActivityCheckbox(Key) + Activity Name
   ->ActivityCheckbox(Key) + Activity Name
```

I have no clue how to bind this in a meaningful way to fit the requirements.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AbdouMoumen I can if I need to.

Comment: So, you would like to show all "Activities" and check those that exist in the "Camp", is that correct?

Comment: AbdouMoumen yes, that's correct

Comment: Would you like to like "checking the CheckBox" to induce adding the checked activity to the Camp's activity list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before binding create a `PagedCollectionView`.
create a new `PropertyGroupDescription`, specifying the name of the column you want to group by.
Add the `PropertyGroupDescription` to the `PagedCollectionView` and then bind the grid to the `PagedCollectionView`.